# Concerns with listiterator remove java

Tags: java, listiterator

I am trying to work the Josephus problem in an arrayList data structure and the task is to use ListIterator. I am getting stuck at the removing part.

Lets say I have following 10 soldiers - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
And I have to step every 3rd soldier - which means remove 3, then 6, then 9, and so on.

I am able to successfully remove 3, but next time it removes 7 and not 6. Can you please review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
private static int suicide (List<Integer> list, int step) {

        ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()&& list.size() != 1){

            if((itr.nextIndex()+1) % step == 0) {
                System.out.println(itr.previousIndex()+1);
                itr.next();
                itr.remove();
                itr.next();
            }
            else {
                itr.next();
            }

            if(!itr.hasNext() ){

                itr=list.listIterator();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that the issue is that the elements move in index and that according to my logic now element 7 is in index '5' (logically 6) and thus gets removed. I want to understand how to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is, that you make a copy of the list, and remove the items in that copy, still iterating the "original" (and skipping on iterator step in the copy).

ListIterator itr = list.listIterator();
ListIterator itr2 = copy.listIterator();

```
while(itr.hasNext()&& list.size() != 1){

    if((itr.nextIndex()+1) % step == 0) {
        System.out.println(itr.previousIndex()+1);
        itr.next();
        itr2.next();
        itr2.remove();
        itr.next();
    }
    else {
            itr.next();
            itr2.next();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
int i = 3;
int step = 1;

while (list.size()  > i) {
    list.remove(i);
    step++;
    i = 3 * step - step + 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revert you design logic !

Building a new List with accepted elements only is a really best approach.

Removing is always harder to understand and to maintain.

For example you methode suicide should return a new List<> with the elements you want.

Your code will be really simpler :

```
List<Integer> cleanedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Integer soldier : list) {
    if(solider%3!=0){
        cleanedList.add(soldier); 
    }     
}
return cleanedList;
```

The most of the time I prefer API that creates new objets. If you apply this rule you code will always get simpler code ! And updating parameters is not a good behavior : if you call the method twice, you obtains two differents results.

Comment: But in first order he wants to remove every 3rd entry (so I understood it), and not just an entry which can divided by 3. Your code works for his "Let's say"-example, where they are perfectly ordered and start with 1.

Comment: You are right but you can do this with index with for(int i=0) and it works where i is your list index